# How to setup bidirectional messaging channel with nodejs zeromq library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

I see in https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js an example of how to use pub/sub pattern.

How do I configure it to not just subscriber receive messages and process them but reply with other messages that go back to publisher?

Answer (score 3):

Given your interest in [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system)-s is going to stay longer, the ZeroMQ garrage, with the most trivial access-nodes' behaviour-archetypes of `{ PUB, XPUB, SUB, XSUB, PUSH, PULL, REQ, XREQ, REP, XREP, PAIR }` will soon stop to match your real-world design needs.

This said, the best one single thing to realise at this very moment is - do not overestimate the built-in trivial archetypes ( these serve as LEGO building blocks - handy to start with, but more powerful if used in some larger concept ).

So,
you may live with having both the **`PUB/SUB`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern and add another one, to be served concurrently in your task

```
// SUB-side_extended_to_TELL_PUB-side_a_word_or_two.js
var zmq  = require('zeromq')
  , sock = zmq.socket('sub')
  , repl = zmq.socket('push');

sock.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
repl.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:3123');

sock.subscribe('kitty cats');
console.log('Subscriber connected to port 3000');

sock.on('message', function(topic, message) {
  console.log( 'INF: Topic-filter:[', topic, '] sent:', message );
  repl.send(   'Got another one' );
  console.log( 'INF: have informed the PUB-side ...' );
});
```

---

### An Epilogue:

Community members, who've spent some time here, on Stack Overflow, might be annoyed by this repeated warning, but, yet - it has an indispensable informative meaning for all those, who have not been here so often or not yet so far:

The **`REQ/REP`** is not a smart way to go. This primitive messaging pattern is fragile as it can fall into an unsalvageable mutual deadlock, so beware to use it in real-world, production-grade software tool. It can live ( and often lives in many such ) school-book examples, but at least, you have been warned...